# On the local measurability

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ a $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_n$ of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We say that a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is *locally in* $\mathcal{M}$ if for every $x \in A$ there is a nbhd $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \cap U \in \mathcal{M}$. Prove that $A$ is in $\mathcal{M}$ iff $A$ is locally in $\mathcal{M}$.

And there is something that doesn't run; in particular $(\Longleftarrow)$ is giving me some problems ( - $(\Longrightarrow)$ is almost trivial). I know that if $A$ were bounded and close, then it would be compact and I might use this property to extract the subcover which I need. If $A$ were only close (and not bounded) I might consider the compact cover $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [-i,i]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and then I might reduce the problem to the previous one - but anyway what I know is only that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{x} U_x$, and not that $\overline{A} \subseteq \bigcup_{x} U_x$. So this is far to be a decisive idea.

I notice also that one might use the (generalization of) [Lindelöf's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f%27s_lemma), and then solve the exercise, but at the point of the course which I'm attending the professor hasn't spoken about it, yet.

So I'm only looking for a little hint because I would like to solve it by myself.

Thank you.